# $2$ Buttons, one with instant $\$1~\text{m}$ and one with $50\%$ of $\$100~\text{m}$

Tags: probability

There are two buttons.

One button gives you $\$1~\text{m}$.

Another button gives you a $50\%$ chance of receiving $\$100~\text{m}$.

You and a friend agree to both press the $\$100~\text{m}$ button and share winnings despite who wins, what is the chances that both of you will receive $\$100~\text{m}$ or more?

What are the chances if it were you and another $3$ friends?

What formula do you use to figure this out?

**EDIT**
I was able to figure out the chances of winning $0 was 6.25%

Comment: Nothing, just saw a meme on facebook and I'm curious what the formula is

Comment: I am not sure "meme" is the word you are looking for. Post may be more appropriate.

Comment: Can you figure out the chances that if you and your friend each flip a fair coin you will both see a head?

Comment: "what is the chances that both of you will receive \$100 m or more?"  How can you both win more than \$100? \$100 m is the maximum either of you can win.  When you say "you both win \$100 m" do you mean that she wins and you win and together you win \$200 m?  Or do you mean that one or the other or both of you win and together you  your total is \$100 or more? grammatically as worded, it should mean the first.  But it sounds like you mean the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula will be: $$1-\left(\frac12\right)^n$$ where $n$ is the no. of people.

**Note:**
$n < 100$ because after that the probability will be $1$

Comment: Try `\left(\frac12\right)^n` giving $\left(\frac12\right)^n$.

Comment: @robjohn thanks!

Comment: So, it's a case of "the more the merrier?"

Comment: Yes,  especially if you have $100$ people or more.